# How to get unique match count in excel

Tags: excel

I have following data in excel.

```
ID        Response
T-1       Yes
T-1       Yes
T-1       No
T-2       No
T-2       No
T-2       No
```

I need to get count in combination with Unique `ID` and `Response`.

Required output:

- Count with unique `ID` having any Response as `Yes`.
- Count with unique `ID` having all Response as `No`.
- Count with unique `ID` having mixed Response as `Yes` and `No`

Comment: How you will count `mixed response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my below screenshot use following formulas.

```
D2=UNIQUE(A2:A7) 'If you do not have Unique() function then need to use some other formula or type unique IDs manually
E2=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,$D2,$B$2:$B$7,E$1)
G2=IF(OR(E2=0,F2=0),"No","Yes")
```

[image]